# Struggling to adjust cell height with increase in content

Tags: ios, swift

I have been struggling greatly almost regularly to be able to create a cell whose height adjusts with content while trying to do it programatically, some things i am trying are , image shows the problem

[image]

1. use below function

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {      
               return UITableView.automaticDimension
          }
   ```

2)Use this in viewDidLoad

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

3. Setting `bottom and top constraints to equal rather then not equal`

Below i paste some code to show my struggle or trying every thing to get the cell to expand with content, which it does. not, can any one please suggest some ways to achieve it

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
      let cell = restaurantMainTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantMainViewCells.self), for: indexPath) as! RestaurantMainViewCells
       
      cell.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 60).isActive = true
      view.addSubview(cell)
      view.addSubview(cell.contentView)
      view.addSubview(cell.restaurantName)
      view.addSubview(cell.restaurantType)
      view.addSubview(cell.restaurantLocation)
      view.addSubview(cell.restaurantMiniImage)
      view.addSubview(cell.restaurantHeartImage)
       
      cell.restaurantHeartImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      cell.restaurantMiniImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      cell.restaurantName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      cell.restaurantLocation.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      cell.restaurantType.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       
       
      //Fonts
      let font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 18)
          let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
          
      let labels = [cell.restaurantName, cell.restaurantLocation, cell.restaurantType]
          labels.forEach { label in
            label.font = fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: font!)
          }
       
      let stackLabels = UIStackView()
      view.addSubview(stackLabels)
      
      stackLabels.alignment = .top
      stackLabels.distribution = .fill
      stackLabels.spacing = 5
      stackLabels.axis = .vertical
       
      stackLabels.addArrangedSubview(cell.restaurantName)
      stackLabels.addArrangedSubview(cell.restaurantType)
      stackLabels.addArrangedSubview(cell.restaurantLocation)
       
      let stackImage = UIStackView()
      view.addSubview(stackImage)
      stackLabels.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      stackImage.alignment = .top
      stackImage.distribution = .fill
      stackImage.axis = .horizontal
      stackImage.spacing = 5
       
       
      cell.restaurantMiniImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
      cell.restaurantMiniImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
      cell.restaurantMiniImage.layer.cornerRadius = 30
      cell.restaurantMiniImage.clipsToBounds = true
       
      cell.restaurantHeartImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
      cell.restaurantHeartImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
      cell.restaurantHeartImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
      cell.restaurantHeartImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
       
       
       
      stackImage.addArrangedSubview(cell.restaurantMiniImage)
      stackImage.addArrangedSubview(stackLabels)
       
      view.addSubview(stackImage)
      stackImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      stackImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
      stackImage.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
     //  stackImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
      
      stackImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.restaurantHeartImage.leadingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    //  stackImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
      stackImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: cell.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
       
      cell.restaurantName.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].name
      cell.restaurantType.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].type
      cell.restaurantLocation.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].location
      cell.restaurantHeartImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart-tick")
      if let restaurantImage = restaurants[indexPath.row].image {
        cell.restaurantMiniImage.image = UIImage(data: restaurantImage as Data)
      }
       
       
      
       
      return cell
       
    default:
      fatalError("no data found")
       
       
    }
  }
```

UPDATE - The whole class

```
//
//  RestaurantMainController.swift
//  LaVivaRepeat
//

//

    import UIKit
    import CoreData
    
    class RestaurantMainController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
        
        var restaurants: [Restaurant] = []
        var fetchResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<Restaurant>!
        
        
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return restaurants.count
        }
        
        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            
            return 1
        }
        
        
        
        
        let restaurantMainTable = UITableView()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            view.addSubview(restaurantMainTable)
            //MARK:- add delegates as self, always, else no contact with model will take place
            restaurantMainTable.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
            restaurantMainTable.estimatedRowHeight = 60
            
            self.restaurantMainTable.delegate = self
            self.restaurantMainTable.dataSource = self
            self.restaurantMainTable.separatorStyle = .singleLine
            //MARK:- create a view to show when no records are there
            let backGroundView = UIView()
            view.addSubview(backGroundView)
            
            backGroundView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
            
            
            let backGroundImage = UIImageView()
            backGroundImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            backGroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            backGroundImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
            backGroundImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320).isActive = true
            backGroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "empty")
            backGroundView.addSubview(backGroundImage)
            
            backGroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
            backGroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 90).isActive = true
            backGroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
            restaurantMainTable.backgroundView = backGroundView
            restaurantMainTable.backgroundView?.isHidden = true
            
            
            
            //MARK:- Add constraints to table
            
            self.restaurantMainTable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.restaurantMainTable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
            self.restaurantMainTable.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            self.restaurantMainTable.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            self.restaurantMainTable.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            
            //MARK:- register RestaurantMainViewCells
            self.restaurantMainTable.register(RestaurantMainViewCells.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantMainViewCells.self))
            
            //MARK:- Get fetch request
            
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Restaurant> = Restaurant.fetchRequest()
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
            
            if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
                let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
                fetchResultController.delegate = self
                
                do {
                    try fetchResultController.performFetch()
                    if let fetchObject = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects {
                        restaurants = fetchObject
                    }
                }
                    
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            restaurantMainTable.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                let cell = restaurantMainTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantMainViewCells.self), for: indexPath) as! RestaurantMainViewCells
                
                // cell.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 60).isActive = true
                view.addSubview(cell)
                view.addSubview(cell.contentView)
                view.addSubview(cell.restaurantName)
                view.addSubview(cell.restaurantType)
                view.addSubview(cell.restaurantLocation)
                view.addSubview(cell.restaurantMiniImage)
                view.addSubview(cell.restaurantHeartImage)
                
                cell.restaurantHeartImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                cell.restaurantMiniImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                cell.restaurantName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                cell.restaurantLocation.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                cell.restaurantType.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                
                
                //Fonts
                let font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 18)
                let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
                
                let labels = [cell.restaurantName, cell.restaurantLocation, cell.restaurantType]
                labels.forEach { label in
                    label.font = fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: font!)
                }
                
                let stackLabels = UIStackView()
                view.addSubview(stackLabels)
                
                stackLabels.alignment = .top
                stackLabels.distribution = .fill
                stackLabels.spacing = 5
                stackLabels.axis = .vertical
                
                stackLabels.addArrangedSubview(cell.restaurantName)
                stackLabels.addArrangedSubview(cell.restaurantType)
                stackLabels.addArrangedSubview(cell.restaurantLocation)
                
                let stackImage = UIStackView()
                view.addSubview(stackImage)
                stackLabels.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                stackImage.alignment = .top
                stackImage.distribution = .fill
                stackImage.axis = .horizontal
                stackImage.spacing = 5
                
                
                cell.restaurantMiniImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
                cell.restaurantMiniImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
                cell.restaurantMiniImage.layer.cornerRadius = 30
                cell.restaurantMiniImage.clipsToBounds = true
                
                cell.restaurantHeartImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
                cell.restaurantHeartImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
                cell.restaurantHeartImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
                cell.restaurantHeartImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
                
                
                
                stackImage.addArrangedSubview(cell.restaurantMiniImage)
                stackImage.addArrangedSubview(stackLabels)
                
                view.addSubview(stackImage)
                stackImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                stackImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
                stackImage.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
                //  stackImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
                
                stackImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.restaurantHeartImage.leadingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
                //  stackImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
                stackImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: cell.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
                
                cell.restaurantName.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].name
                cell.restaurantType.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].type
                cell.restaurantLocation.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].location
                cell.restaurantHeartImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart-tick")
                if let restaurantImage = restaurants[indexPath.row].image {
                    cell.restaurantMiniImage.image = UIImage(data: restaurantImage as Data)
                }
                
                
                
                
                return cell
                
            default:
                fatalError("no data found")
                
                
            }
        }
        //MARK:- Make custom navigation bar large font size and use rubik fonts
        
        
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            
            
            
            navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "LaViva Hotel"
            navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
            navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
            
            if let customFont = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 40) {
                navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 200/255, green: 70/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: 1), NSAttributedString.Key.font: customFont]
            }
            
            //MARK:- for empty table
            if restaurants.count > 0 {
                self.restaurantMainTable.backgroundView?.isHidden = true
                self.restaurantMainTable.separatorStyle = .singleLine
                
            }
            else {
                self.restaurantMainTable.backgroundView?.isHidden = false
                self.restaurantMainTable.separatorStyle = .none
                
            }
            
            //MARK:- make an + button appear on top left
            let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "plus"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addNewRestaurant))
            
            //navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
            
        }
        
        //MARK:- addNewRestaurant function
        @objc func addNewRestaurant() {
            let pushController = RestaurantAddController()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(pushController, animated: true)
        }
        
        //MARK:- try and show cell and tower as default or dark done here
        
        
        override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
            return .default
        }
        
        
        //add update delete
        
        func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
            restaurantMainTable.beginUpdates()
        }
        
        func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
            switch type {
            case .insert:
                if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    restaurantMainTable.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
                }
                
            case .delete:
                if let indexPath = indexPath {
                    restaurantMainTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                }
                
            case .update:
                if let indexPath = indexPath {
                    restaurantMainTable.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                }
            default:
                restaurantMainTable.reloadData()
                
            }
            
            if let fetchedObjects = controller.fetchedObjects {
                restaurants = fetchedObjects as! [Restaurant]
            }
        }
        
        
        func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
            restaurantMainTable.endUpdates()
            
            
            
        }
        
        //MARK:- left swipr delete
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, completionHandler) in
                
                if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
                    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                    let restaurantsToDelete = self.fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)
                    context.delete(restaurantsToDelete)
                    appDelegate.saveContext()
                }
                
                completionHandler(true)
                
            }
            
            let swipeConfiguration: UISwipeActionsConfiguration
            swipeConfiguration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
            return swipeConfiguration
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
        
        
        
        
        
    }
```

UPDATE

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantMainViewCells: UITableViewCell {
    
    var restaurantMiniImage = UIImageView()
       
    var restaurantHeartImage = UIImageView()
    var restaurantName = UILabel()
    var restaurantType = UILabel()
    var restaurantLocation = UILabel()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh!!!! Very, very wrong. Have you designed your cell as a Prototype in Storyboard? Or via code in a `class RestaurantMainViewCells: UITableViewCell` class?

Comment: @DonMag - in a class , i deleted the storyboard

Comment: ok - edit your question and include the code for your cell class.

Comment: @DonMag - i posted the whole class

Comment: You didn't post your `class RestaurantMainViewCells: UITableViewCell` class?

Comment: @DonMAg - i posted it now

Comment: well cellForRow method is not for adding subviews to cell ... add them in cell class and just update values in cellForRow method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your cell setup - adding and constraining UI elements - should be done in your cell class. ***Absolutely NOT*** in `cellForRowAt`.

You would do well to go through a few tutorials on creating dynamic cells.

But, to give you an idea, here is your code modified so you can see what's happening:

```
struct Restaurant {
    var name: String = ""
    var type: String = ""
    var location: String = ""
    
    // however you have your image information stored
    //var image
}

class RestaurantMainViewCells: UITableViewCell {
    
    var restaurantMiniImage = UIImageView()
    var restaurantHeartImage = UIImageView()
    var restaurantName = UILabel()
    var restaurantType = UILabel()
    var restaurantLocation = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        // so we can see the image view frames without actual images...
        restaurantMiniImage.backgroundColor = .green
        restaurantHeartImage.backgroundColor = .red
        
        var font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        
        if let f = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 18) {
            font = f
        }
        let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)

        let labels = [restaurantName, restaurantLocation, restaurantType]
        labels.forEach { label in
            label.font = fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: font)
            // so we can see label frames...
            label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
        
        let stackLabels = UIStackView()
        stackLabels.alignment = .fill
        stackLabels.distribution = .fill
        stackLabels.spacing = 5
        stackLabels.axis = .vertical
        
        stackLabels.addArrangedSubview(restaurantName)
        stackLabels.addArrangedSubview(restaurantType)
        stackLabels.addArrangedSubview(restaurantLocation)
        
        let stackImage = UIStackView()
        stackImage.alignment = .top
        stackImage.distribution = .fill
        stackImage.axis = .horizontal
        stackImage.spacing = 5
        
        restaurantMiniImage.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        restaurantMiniImage.clipsToBounds = true
        
        stackImage.addArrangedSubview(restaurantMiniImage)
        stackImage.addArrangedSubview(stackLabels)
        contentView.addSubview(stackImage)
        contentView.addSubview(restaurantHeartImage)
        
        restaurantHeartImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // mini image 60x60
            restaurantMiniImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            restaurantMiniImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
            
            // heart image 20 x 20
            restaurantHeartImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            restaurantHeartImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            
            // heart image top+20 trailing-10
            restaurantHeartImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            restaurantHeartImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),

            // horizontal stack top / leading / bottom  and trailinh to heart image
            // all with 10-pts "padding"
            stackImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            stackImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            
            stackImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: restaurantHeartImage.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),
            stackImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            
        ])
        
    }
}

class RestaurantMainController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var restaurants: [Restaurant] = []
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return restaurants.count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    let restaurantMainTable = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(restaurantMainTable)
        
        //MARK:- add delegates as self, always, else no contact with model will take place
        restaurantMainTable.estimatedRowHeight = 60
        
        self.restaurantMainTable.delegate = self
        self.restaurantMainTable.dataSource = self

        self.restaurantMainTable.separatorStyle = .singleLine

        //MARK:- Add constraints to table
        self.restaurantMainTable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            restaurantMainTable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            restaurantMainTable.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            restaurantMainTable.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            restaurantMainTable.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        
        //MARK:- register RestaurantMainViewCells
        self.restaurantMainTable.register(RestaurantMainViewCells.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantMainViewCells.self))
        
        //MARK:- Get fetch request

        // I don't have your "fetch" data, so I'm just adding a couple restaurants here
        restaurants.append(Restaurant(name: "Cafe De Loir", type: "Chinese Cousine", location: "Hong Kong"))
        restaurants.append(Restaurant(name: "Bob's Cafe", type: "Japanese Cousine", location: "Tokyo"))
        restaurants.append(Restaurant(name: "Mary's Restaurant", type: "Home Cooking", location: "Dallas, Texas"))

        //      let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Restaurant> = Restaurant.fetchRequest()
        //      let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        //      fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        //
        //      if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
        //          let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        //          fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        //          fetchResultController.delegate = self
        //
        //          do {
        //              try fetchResultController.performFetch()
        //              if let fetchObject = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects {
        //                  restaurants = fetchObject
        //              }
        //          }
        //
        //          catch {
        //              print(error)
        //          }
        //      }

    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantMainViewCells.self), for: indexPath) as! RestaurantMainViewCells
        
        let r = restaurants[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.restaurantName.text = r.name
        cell.restaurantType.text = r.type
        cell.restaurantLocation.text = r.location

        //if let restaurantImage = restaurants[indexPath.row].image {
        //  cell.restaurantMiniImage.image = UIImage(data: restaurantImage as Data)
        //}
        
        cell.restaurantHeartImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart-tick")

        return cell
        
    }
    
}
```

The result (I don't have your images so the image views have green or red background color):

[image]